# Mock a constructor with MOQ

Tags: c#, moq

I have a class B with a constructor parameter of Type class A.

I want that class A is mocked when I create a mock for class B.

How can I do this? I tried MockBehavior Loose/Strict but this did not help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are mocking classes you can pass in the constructor arguments when calling `new Mock<T>`:

So if you have the classes:

```
public class A {}

public class B
{
    private readonly A a;

    public B(A a) { this.a = a; }
}
```

The following code creates a mock B with a mock A:

```
var mockA = new Mock<A>();
var mockB = new Mock<B>(mockA.Object);
```

Comment: Is there no posibility to say like in TypeMock Constructor.Mocked ?

Comment: @Elisa I am not too familiar with TypeMock but if I understood correctly this Constructor.Mocked feature then you are not able to this with Moq. E.g it cannot mock out constructors or write expectations for constructor calls.

Comment: The reason why I mentioned was that I want to save the creation of the mockA object by saying var mockB = new Mock<B>(Constructor.Mocked). that way I have not to create mockA :)