# How to mock a class that has parameters in the constructor using Mock.Of<> syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420618/mock-a-constructor-with-moq) has showed me how to mock a class that has parameters in the constructor. Here's a [nice block post](https://cmatskas.com/improve-your-unit-tests-with-mock-of/) on the `Mock.Of<>`, but it doesn't show how to mock the constructor using function syntax.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IDependency1 dep1, IDependency2 dep2, IDependency3 dep3)
    {}

    public ReturnType MyNewMethod(Tyep1 t1, Type2 t2)
    {
       //1. call to ExistingMethod1();
       //2. call to ExistingMethod2();
       //3. call using the DbContext
       //4. call using the Logger
    }
}
```

I get something like this based of the first blog post.

```
var dep1 = new Mock<IDependency1>(); 
var dep2 = new Mock<IDependency2>();
var dep3 = new Mock<IDependency3>();

object[] arrParams = { dep1.Object, dep2.Object, dep3.Object }
var sut = new Mock<MyClass>(arrParams);
```

So how to mock a class that has parameters in the constructor using `Mock.Of<>` syntax?

## EDIT

the new method will not only call **existing methods**, but also access the `DbContext`, the `logger`, and maybe other services. So, I need to mock everything but the method I am testing.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MyDbContext context, ISecurityService secService, ILogger logger)
    {}

    public ReturnType1 ExistingMethod1(Type1 t1){}

    public ReturnType2 ExistingMethod2(Type t){}

    public MyEntity MyNewMethod(Tyep1 t1, Type2 t2)
    {
       //1. call to ExistingMethod1(); --> I'll just setup the return value
       //2. call to ExistingMethod2(); --> I'll just setup the return value
       //3. call using the DbContext   --> ???
       //4. call using the Logger      --> ???

       var x = ExistingMethod1(t1);                //1.
       var y = ExistingMethod1(x);                 //2.

       var result context.MyEntities.              //3.
              .Where(e => e.id == y.MyEntityId)
              .ToList();

       return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not certain the `Mock.Of` allows this, I'll have to recheck.

Comment: You can use the linq version for the dependencies and the standard one for the subject class

Comment: why do you need to mock a constructor?  The idea of mocking for unit testing is to just isolate the class under test from external dependencies. Once you mock, in your case dep1, dep2,dep3 , you just create MyClass object passing the mock. No need to mock the constructor

Comment: Have a look at the docs here https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks

Comment: Further to @DanHunex question. Is there a particular reason you are trying to mock the concrete class?

Comment: @DanHunex, I'm not tryig to mock the constructor. The class I am mocking has a constructor that takes parameters. So how do I mock that class using the functional syntax. Actually, this is what I'm trying to write `var sut = new Mock<MyClass>(arrParams);` using `Mock.Of<>`

Comment: Yes. That is the beauty of mocking. You don't care about constructor of a class you are going to mock. The mock will create dynamic proxy for that class , that is why your class should have virtual methods or implement interface. Just mock it Mock<MyClass> myObj = new Mock<MyClass>()  but make sure the methods are virtual

Comment: This now appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem

Comment: You would need to provide constructor arguments if you were mocking an abstract class without a default constructor, or a concrete class which has a virtual method to be mocked. I don't think you can do this with `Mock.Of` though. Just just `new Mock<T>(args)` or use an interface as your abstraction mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking with Moq need the class to be mocked to have methods to be virtual or you can mock any interface. When you are mocking with moq, it will create a dynamic implementation on the fly and thus it does not depend on your implementation. In your case you can just do

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IDependency1 dep1, IDependency2 dep2, IDependency3 dep3)
    {}

    public ReturnType MyNewMethod(Tyep1 t1, Type2 t2)
    {
       //1. call to ExistingMethod1(); --> I'll just setup the return value
       //2. call to ExistingMethod2(); --> I'll just setup the return value
       //3. call using the DbContext   --> ???
       //4. call using the Logger      --> ???
    }
}

    Mock<MyClass> mockedObj = new Mock<MyClass>();

    mockedObj.SetUp(x=>x.MyNewMethod()).Returns(objectOfReturnType);
```

Here you need to make MyNewMethod virtual. The return objectOfReturnType is an object you created as test object. so your method body detail is not required or needed. That is the idea of mocking, you are mocking your actual implementation with fake implementation ( which is the setup in this case). You can vary different return objects depending how you will test the class under test. I recommend you first to read unit testing 101.

Note that you are setting up how MyNewMethod behave. Your implementation might be doing lots of stuff but here what you care is its return. That is why the method also has to be virtual, it will be overriden by the Moq and return what you just setup. Internally that method might call different things...so you don't care

Also you should read the basic of Moq, you can find it here https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Make sense. Now, there are 2 issues that I am trying to solve. 1) the method I am adding to this service class calls other methods in the same class. With the code you put above, that issue will be taken care of. 2) my method also depends on the DbContext, Logger, and so forth. So if I don't add them to the constructor, how am I going to control their behavior. That's really the confustion I'm having.

Comment: No you just mock one level of dependency. Otherwise, it is not anymore unit test. If you are test Class2 which depends on MyClass, you just mock Myclass and never worry about its dependency. You setup the methods as to what they should return depending on your input. if you share the class you want to share, I can give you some direction how to mock dependencies and setup method of those dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test `MyClass` you might want to mock the dependencies instead:

```
// Arrange
var mockDep1 = new Mock<IDependency1>();
var mockDep2 = new Mock<IDependency2>();
var mockDep3 = new Mock<IDependency3>();

var myTestInstance = new MyClass(mockDep1.Object, mockDep2.Object, mockDep3.Object);

// Act
var result = myTestInstance.DoSomething();

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(result, myExpectedResult); // check the direct result
mockDep1.Verify(mock => mock.SomeMethodOnMock(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once); // SomeMethodOnMock was called once
// ... etc
```

On the other hand, if *`MyClass` is the dependency you want to mock for another test object*, then the best way to extract an interface from it (eg. `IMyClass`) so you can test your class in a much cleaner way.

Moq allows you to mock non-sealed classes but it is rather a fail-safe if there is no other way as many irrelevant code may be executed during the test and you can setup/verify non-sealed virtual or abstract members only.

Comment: Let's say I'm adding a method called `MyNewMethod()` that I am testing. This method is calling a couple of existing method `ExistingMethod1()` and `ExistingMethod2()`. When I look at your code, I see that you didn't mock `MyClass`. When I test the new method, it's going to call the `REAL` version of the 2 existing methods (with all their complexity). I thought they should be mocked.

Comment: @Richard77: So if I understand well you test `MyClass`. In this case `MyClass` should _not_ be mocked. It is alright if its existing methods are called during the test because they belong to the class, which is tested. However, _dependencies_ of `MyClass` aren't desired to be called, as they don't belong to your class and you would just test 3rd party codes, at least partially. That's why Moq exists. You can setup the members of the mocked dependencies to return some dummy code if necessary and you can assert if those members were called.